# HTML Form Pattern Beginning Digit

Tags: html

How do I validate only when the first digit is 6,9 or 8 (currently allows 8 digits number)?

this is my current code

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="contactNumber" placeholder="8 Digits Contact Number"  pattern="[0-9]{8}" required="" name="contactnumber">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern **[6|8|9][0-9]{7}** input type = text

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactNumber" placeholder="8 Digits Contact Number"  pattern="[6|8|9][0-9]{7}" required="" name="contactnumber">
```

first digit is  6 or 8 or 9 followed by 7 other digit.

Comment: This regex doesn't work for what the OP asked.
go to [regexr](http://regexr.com/) and try this valid number 87654321

Comment: Its working check this demo that i have created with the number you have given  regexr -
http://regexr.com/3ggm4

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a bad copy of the pattern. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(6|8|9)\d{7}
```

Checks if the first char is one of the 3 options and then matches any other 7 digits.